How to read Nullable Records in BigQuery to Pandas dataframe?
When querying a nullable record in BigQuery client, the client returns each element within a nullable record as a column, but when doing it in Python into a Pandas DF, the each element in the nullable record is formatted as a JSON and then put into one column. Is there a way to prevent this?
Hoping this is possible without just unloading the jsons and adding them to the dataframe manually

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
